# What famous attacks used a use-after-free vulnerability?

Tags: attacks, vulnerability, use-after-free

I'm compiling vulnerabilities and related attacks, and I need to find a famous attack that exploited a use-after-free vulnerability. I've looked for a while though I can't seem to find any. I know there are lots of times use-after-frees were found in internet explorer and other softwares, though I only get pointed to the vulnerability and update pages, and not specific attacks.

Comment: Google-Fu it up:  https://www.purehacking.com/blog/lloyd-simon/an-introduction-to-use-after-free-vulnerabilities

Comment: So, you are looking for a high profile attack that used an exploit for this specific vulnerability? Are you looking for PoCs (there are lots)? Are you looking for CVEs?

Answer (score 2):

[How we broke PHP, hacked Pornhub and earned $20,000](https://www.evonide.com/how-we-broke-php-hacked-pornhub-and-earned-20000-dollar/)

> We have found two use-after-free vulnerabilities in PHP’s garbage collection algorithm.
>   Those vulnerabilities were remotely exploitable over PHP’s unserialize function.